# Haskell - how to access lists within lists

Tags: haskell

I have this function that I need to build for my assignment.

This function returns a list of all symbols (without duplicates) in all input sentences.  Where Sentence and Symbol are the following types:

```
-- Symbols are strings (a negative sign as the first character represents a negated symbol)
type Symbol = String  

-- Sentence = Statements. This is a list of a list of symbols
type Sentence = [[Symbol]]
```

I have tried with list comprehension and recursion, but I don't know how to access list within lists. Also you don't need to have any duplicates , for this I used nub function as:

```
getSymbols :: [Sentence] -> [Symbol]
getSymbols stmts = nub [ x | [x: xs] <- stmts ]
```

```
Input:   getSymbols [["A"], ["B","C"], ["C"]]
Return:  ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Really appreciate for some help!

Comment: When working with markdown (e.g. code on StackOverflow), indent all your code lines by four spaces. See also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursively you can define your concatenation like

```
conc [] = []
conc (x:xs) = x ++ (conc xs) -- ++ concatenates two lists
```

Your `getSymbols` becomes

```
getSymbols sentence = nub . conc $ sentence
```

About:

```
getSymbols :: [Sentence] -> [Symbol]
```

Are you sure that you want to take a list of sentences there? It seems that you're trying to work with only one sentence, especially when looking at your example input & output. If you want to work with a list of sentences then you can `conc` twice to bring all of the symbols to the same level.

```
getSymbols' :: [Sentence] -> [Symbol]
getSymbols' sentences = nub . conc . conc $ sentences
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adapting something like

```
[ 1000 + x | xs <- [[1,2],[3,4]] , x <- xs ]
```